# What does a yellow damage indicator mean?

Tags: call-of-duty-infinite-warfare

I've seen both red and yellow damage indicators in this game.  What does a yellow indicator mean?  I haven't been able to determine a difference between them.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: damage indicator]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The yellow damage indicator is the result of taking damage from reflections. Reflections only come from energy weapons, and bounce off of walls once. A specific attachment, the Ram Servo, can make the projectile bounce a second time.

Source: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9VjAFL4QgY)

As the video states, reflections appear to do ~65% of bullet damage. There are no hard-coded stats yet, so this is an estimation.

Comment: @Dpeif This question was strictly for multiplayer, i would assume. I haven't played the Zombies mode myself, but I don't know why a zombie hitting you would display a yellow hit; they can't exactly headshot you?

Comment: I was asking about this strictly for multiplayer.  In the zombies, friendly fire is not possible, and zombies do not have guns to shot at you.  I also do not think its possible to shoot yourself with a ricocheted bullet.